# Dashing Dashboard Widgets Won't Display - Invalid API key

Tags: dashing

I've been following the steps in the Dashing workshop here: https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/wiki/Dashing-Workshop

This is my first time working with Dashing and I'm trying to get familiar with how it all works.

I've been trying to get my dashboard to display a widget as in the above link but no widget will appear. I've gotten through step 3 up to the point where I'm supposed to curl the api.

So I type the following into my command line:

```html
curl -d "{\"auth_token\": \"ABC\", \"value\": 300 }" http://localhost:3030/widgets/response_time
```

and I get the error invalid API key. As a result my dashboard doesn't end up displaying my widget. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong however because my auth_token is set to ABC in my config.ru file.

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem? If anymore of my code is needed just let me know.

**Edit:** So I figured out that two things were going on here. The reason my widgets weren't displaying was because I didn't have Node.JS installed. Now my widget is displaying but I'm still getting the invalid API key error.

Comment: Can you please paste the part of your config.ru where you set the API key? Or put the whole thing in a pastie/gist/something?

That should work and does for me...

Comment: I ended up restarting my cmd line and it mysteriously stopped giving me the invalid API key error. I guess the only problem was that I didn't have Node.JS installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by installing Node.JS, restarting my cmd line and recurling the url.